# how to make a control visible in a panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a control to my panel in WinForms.

```
public Form1()
{
       InitializeComponent();
       PictureBox a = new PictureBox();
       a.Left = 100;
       a.Top = 150;
       a.Width = 50;
       a.Height = 50; 
       a.BackColor = Color.Red;
       Controls.Add(a);    
}
```

Without the Panel, this code works perfect. But the Panel blocks the PictureBox, which properties should I change?

Comment: Use BringToFront().  Or add the picture box to the panel.

Comment: show the code with `Panel`

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you I was looking for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, there are few options to achieve that:

**1.** When you add the controls to your `Form` like this:

```
Controls.Add(panel);
Controls.Add(button1);
Controls.Add(button2);
Controls.Add(pictureBox);
```

They will be shown in this very order: `panel` on the bottom, `buttons` between and `pictureBox` on the top.

**2.** As it was pointed in the comments, you can use `BringToFront()` after adding the control.

```
pictureBox.BringToFront();
```

This will make the `pictureBox` to be on top of other things.

**3.** You can change the order of controls by editing their Z-index, called `ChildIndex` in WinForms. You can set it with:

```
Controls.SetChildIndex(pictureBox, __yourIndex__);
```

**4.** You can add the `pictureBox` to your `panel` with:

```
panel.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
```